# Rotating iPhone and keeping image's proportions

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uiimageview

I have an UIScrollView, that contains UIImageViews. All images keep their image ratio - I mean that e.g. portrait image is high and narrow, while landscape image is short and wide. I have about 4 images at same time on screen (2 vertically, 2 horizontally), then I can scroll down.

My problem is rotating the device. I use

```
[self.imageScrollView setAutoresizingMask: UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin];// (etc)
```

And same method for imageView. But images don't keep their proportions. If I set:
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth - image is wide but heigh is too small
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight - image is stretched horizontally, while vertically it's way to small.

I need to rotate the device (portrait->landscape), make these 2 images (that I have next to each other) to fill gap and keep these images proportions.

Comment: In other words: i want to rotate the device, rotate picture inside UIImageView and save it's x:y ratio (not to stretch).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
```

This solved my problem ^^

Answer (score 0):

Try this function..

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
        if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait) { //Device is portait 
            //Resize the images to fit this orientation
                         image1.frame = CGRectMake(x,x,x,x);
        }
        else {
            //Device is landscape..
        }   
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: There is no other way? There would be so much counting it can be pretty slow this way.. :/